# password_hash() function on php /getting invalid password

Tags: php, security, password-hash, php-password-hash

**I get invalid password by running this code. Why the password didn't match with the hashed one?**

```
<?php
    $passwd = "imad";
    $hash = password_hash($passwd,PASSWORD_DEFAULT,['cost'=>10]);
    echo "$passwd".' :'.$hash."<br/><br/>";


    if (password_verify($passwd, $hash,['cost'=>10])) {
        echo 'Password is valid!';
    }   else {
        echo 'Invalid password.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: what does the hash look like? Does it contain `$`?

Comment: `if (password_verify($passwd, $hash)){ // }` is enough, there's no 3rd parameter when verifying.

Comment: Because you don't have `error_reporting` turned up or you don't have `display_errors` turned on, or you just didn't read the manual. [`password_verify`](http://php.net/password-verify) takes exactly 2 arguments. You're passing in 3 arguments. Which means the function will not return and instead will trigger an error.

Answer (score 0):

`password_verify` expects exactly 2 parameters.

So you need to do just:

```
if(password_verify($passwd, $hash)) { ... }
```

And the above code can be shortened to:

```
(password_verify($passwd, $hash)) ? : echo "Password is valid!" : echo "Password is invalid."
```

by using [ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

---

Also turning `error_reporting` is a good idea, generally when developing.

So put:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

that at the top of your file.

And when you are gonna move that to a production stage, remove them.

Comment: Tnx sir , u made my day :d